# Recursion issue using Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am working on this challenge from FreeCodeCamp

> Flatten a nested array. You must account for varying levels of
>   nesting.

I am trying to solve it using recursion.

Here is my code:

```
function steamroller(arr) {
    var flatArray = [];

    function flatten(obj) {
        if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
            return(obj);
        }
        for (var i in obj) {
            return flatten(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    flatArray.push(flatten(arr));

    console.log(flatArray);
}

steamroller([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

This logs:

```
Array [ 1 ]
```

I can see the problem, the return statement breaks the for loop so only the first value is returned.

However if I leave out the return and just use:

```
flatten(obj[i]);
```

I get back:

```
Array [ undefined ]
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `for ... in` loops to iterate through arrays. Use `.forEach()` or a numeric index in an ordinary `for` loop.

Comment: You can look at underscore's [_.flatten](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L493) :)

Comment: You need to concatenate those results, rather than return each recursively flattened element (note after the first return the function will entirely return).

Comment: These all make sense, just learning JS so forEach is next! Extremely helpful replies and comments, especially the underscore.js one :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code so that it works, adding comments:

```
function steamroller(arr) {
var flatArray = [];

function flatten(obj) {
    if (!Array.isArray(obj)) {
        // We got to the innermost element. Push it to the array.
        flatArray.push(obj); 
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        flatten(obj[i]); // Do not return here.
    }
}

flatten(arr);

console.log(flatArray);
}

steamroller([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
```

Comment: thanks for this, I'm submitting this answer as it represents my current level with Javascript, is this a good approach in your opinion?

Comment: To be honest, CD..'s approach is cleaner as it only uses one function and has no side effects. If your code has to run on node or a modern browser it's probably the best one. Beware however that forEach does not work on older IE versions, so if you wanted complete compatibility you'd have to replace it with an old style for.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the items to the result array.

```
function flatten(arr){
  var flat = [];

  arr.forEach(function(item){     
    flat.push.apply(flat, Array.isArray(item) ? flatten(item) : [item]);      
  });

  return flat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach:

```
function flat(a,f){
 if (!f) var f=[];
 a.forEach(function(e){
  if (Array.isArray(e)) flat(e,f);
  else f.push(e);
 });
 return f;
}

var flatArray=flat(deepArray);
```

The function returns the flattened array each time but ignores its return value in the inner calls of itself (`flat(e,f)`). Instead it keeps pushing each non-Array value to the same `f`-Array that was defined initially in the outer call of `flat(a)`.

Using the second (usually unused) argument you can also concatenate values to an already existing flat array like

```
var a=[[2,4,[5,6,[7,8],[9,10]],1],3];
var fl1=flat(a);
// "2|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|1|3"
var fl2=flat(a,fl1);
// "2|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|1|3|2|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|1|3"
```

Answer (score 1):

A **fully recursive** solution, if you **don't need** to keep the original array intact:

```
function flatten (obj, memo) {
    memo = (memo || []);
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        if (obj.length) {
            // flatten the first element, removing it from the original array
            flatten(obj.shift(), memo);
            // flatten the rest of the original array
            flatten(obj, memo);
        }
        return memo;
    }
    return memo.push(obj);
}
```

We firstly check if `obj` is an array. Then, if it is not empty, flatten the first element, them flatten the rest. If object is not an array, it is returned and pushed into the `memo` array, wich is returned.

Notice that in the first line I'm setting `memo = (memo || [])`. This makes sure we always get a new array in the first call, if `memo` is not set.

Answer (score 0):

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {

  let string = String(arr);
  let strArr = string.split(",");
      
  for (let i in strArr){

    if (strArr[i]==""){
      strArr.splice(i,1); 
      
    }

    if (strArr[i]=="[object Object]"){
      strArr[i] = {}; 
    }

    if (isNaN(parseInt(strArr[i],10))== false){
      strArr[i] = parseInt(strArr[i]); 
    }

  }

  return strArr;

}
```

Comment: Hi, please add an explanation to what you changed

Answer (score 0):

Because this was recently brought back up with a new answer, perhaps it's time to revisit it.

This is a fairly simple recursive process.  When this question was asked, ES5 was ubiquitous and ES6/ES2015 was being implemented everywhere.

A simple ES5 solution would look like this:

```js
const flat = (ns) => 
  ns .map (n => Array .isArray (n) ? flat (n) : n)
     .reduce ((a, b) => a .concat (b), [])
```

but this pattern was made unnecessary by ES6, and that `map-reduce(concat)` pattern could now be written with [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const flatter = (ns) => 
  ns .flatMap(n => Array .isArray (n) ? flatter (n) : n)
```

However, you don't even need to do this, because ES6 also introduced [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), which allows us to write this:

```js
const flattest = (ns) =>
  ns .flat (Infinity)
```

```js
const flat = (ns) => 
  ns .map (n => Array .isArray (n) ? flat (n) : n)
     .reduce ((a, b) => a .concat (b), [])

const flatter = (ns) => 
  ns .flatMap(n => Array .isArray (n) ? flatter (n) : n)

const flattest = (ns) =>
  ns .flat (Infinity)


const data = [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]

console .log (flat (data))
console .log (flatter (data))
console .log (flattest (data))
```